# POWER calculation in microsoft excel

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponentiation

I'm trying to replicate the POWER calculation in microsoft excel using C++.

It's meant to be able to handle real number bases and exponents.

I've tried using a Taylor series expansion but it doesn't match excel output to the desired precision. Especially for really large or small results. Are there other methods (series, iterative or others) to calculate power... Preferably, does anyone know how it's evaluated on excel?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not clear what you really want. Are you trying to implement this function in some programming language? Are your exponents real or just integers? Please provide more context

Comment: Thanks, edited the question